# Node: Writing to a file, maintaining a certain length (createWriteStream?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fs

I need some help.

I have a UDP server that is getting a lot of messages constantly.

I'd like to **write** the **last 50,000 messages** (or a certain KB) that I'm getting to a file.

So, the first 50,000 messages just get appended to a file.

The 50,001th message removes the first line of the file, and appends the message to the bottom of the file.

Right now, it's just appending to the file.. but then the file gets WAY too big, and I just want to remove all the beginning lines until I have around 50,000 lines left. Any ideas on how to do this? This file is getting written to about 150+ times per second

```
udpserver.on("message",
       function (msg, rinfo){
                fs.appendFile("../Logs/Raw-UDP-Log.log", msg.toString()+"\n", function (err) {
                  console.log("Writing to log error: ", err);
                });
        });
```

Comment: if you get 150 lines per seconds written, and you're saving the last 500, you're only saving the last 3~4 seconds of activity. Does that make sense? Would it not make more sense to keep those message in an array in memory instead, writing to it based on a `lines[idx++ % lines.length] = ...` and then dumping that to file on error, not even bothering with the file when nothing's going wrong?

Comment: Yeah, maybe I should increase the number... Maybe when the file gets to 50,000 lines

Comment: You probably want a memory mapped file. The [mmap](https://github.com/geocar/mmap) module should be useful here.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Oh! Yeah, that's a great idea, I didn't think of that! I'm looking at https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-mmap and seeing if i can figure out a way for it to work

Comment: that one's discontinued.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans :( k I'll use the one you linked in a similar fashion as the example in the discontinued library